# search elasticsearch query with like function

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, sql-like

How can I search some data using [URI search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request) in elasticsearch?
I want to do search similar to SQLs `LIKE` functionality

I tried

```
http://****/billing_master/_search?q=CUST_NAME:Komplek*
```

I wish the result would be like :

```
{
  "_index": "billing_master",
  "_type": "90000019",
  "_id": "C20110325000809_371",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "ALAMAT": "Komplek Ruko Jl. By pass Ngurah Rai No.257   Suwung Kangin Denpasar Selatan",
    "CUST_NAME": "PT. Sobek Bali Utama (Cp. I Made Antara)",
    "ANI": "082897030385",
    "CUST_ID": "C20110325000809_371",
    "SCGROUP": 39,
    "EMAIL": "edps@balisobeks.com,indradewis@balisobeks.com,dewis@balisobeks.com",
    "BILLING_ID": "90000019",
    "SOFTORHARD": "03",
    "HCGROUP": 39
  }
}
```

but the real result is

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data model, but I will suggest 2 solutions for this case:

**Solution 1 - Create a nested type for the URI**:

```
{
  "nesttype" : {
        "properties" : {
            "uri" : {
                "type" : "nested" ,
                "properties" : {
                    "host"      : { "type" : "string" },
                    "relativePath"      : { "type" : "string" },
                    "params"    : { "type" : "string" },
                    "paramValues"   : { "type" : "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this nested type, you may create a nested query and search for the fields: "host" as "****", "relativePath" as "billing_master/_search" and "paraValues" as "CUST_NAME:Komplek".

**Solution 2 - Create a string field not analyzed**:

```
{
  "test" : {
        "properties" : {
            "uri" : {
                "type" : "string" ,
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this type of field, the uri won't split into tokens. So you may use a wildcard query.

For more info, read about analyzed field, nested field and nested query.